# ¿En qué países se utiliza la expresión "colgar el sambenito"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, modismos

Como resultado de una [pregunta anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/translation-of-guilt-trip) relacionada con el concepto de culpabilidad (guilt trip), surgió la expresión (frecuente en España) "**colgar el sambenito**", que significa "culpar a alguien injustificadamente" y tiene un [interesante origen histórico](http://definicienciapopular.blogspot.com.es/2008/03/colgar-el-sambenito.html).

¿Es frecuente la expresión "colgar el sambenito a alguien" en otros países de habla hispana? ¿Tiene el mismo significado que en España?

Answer (score 1):

[Este](http://hablandodepalabras.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/colgar-el-sambenito-origen-y-significados/) es un blog en wordpress por lo que su contenido habría que tomarlo con un granito de sal.

De acuerdo con el mismo no en todos los países de habla hispana se utiliza esta expresión como tal, pero existen equivalentes, como ejemplos menciona:

> Cargarle el muerto/muertito. - Se que se usa en México y el blog
>   menciona que se usa también en España y Cuba.
>   Comerse un garrón. - Argentina.

Hasta ahora es todo lo que he podido encontrar.

Comment: En España se usa *Cargarle el muerto* (nunca he oído *muertito*), pero no había oído nunca ni *Comerse un garrón* ni *colgar el sambenito*.

Comment: En Chile pasa lo mismo que comenta @Bousie para el caso de España.

Answer (score 0):

"Colgar el sambenito" o "cargarle el muerto" a alguien son expresiones relativamente habituales en España y que resultan muy poco frecuentes en otros países de habla hispana, donde han prevalecido otras que o bien se encuentran en desuso en Europa o son fruto de la adaptación procedente de otras lenguas.